# Stop view from reseting when I return to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I have an app where you move around a 8x8 grid to differend locations and a button which takes a user to another view and displays some current stats about their character. However, when they go back to the original view they are currently reset to their starting position as is their health. How can I make it so that when they return back to the view, they are at the same x,y coordinates and stats as when they left? Here is what I currently have in my BCAViewController.m viewDidLoad Method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    BCAFactory *factory = [[BCAFactory alloc] init];
    self.tiles = [factory tiles];

    BCACaptain *captain = [[BCACaptain alloc] init];
    self.captainsHealth = 50;

    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

    [self updateTile];
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateCurrentPos];

    captain.health = self.captainsHealth;
    self.healthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", captain.health];

    self.clueText.delegate = self;
```

Comment: show your viewWillAppear and navigation process.

Comment: If you can only have one BCACaptain at a time, then perhaps it should be a singleton or a property of your AppDelegate?

Comment: @Rashad sorry I am a new (I am actually sort of following a tutorial for this although making adjustments) where abouts do I find viewWillAppear? i could not find that method in my BCAViewController

Comment: @harazzy > How you are going forward and returning back to BCAViewController? Please share those navigation process

Comment: @Rashad just via a modal button one on each view